# My mesh deforms while moving a armature in object mode

Tags: animation, objects

I'm trying to do bug walking animation that follows a path but mesh deforms too much especially legs[image] . Btw there is no problem if I move all bones in the pose mode

Answer (score -1):

Adjust the position with using <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>